# Unimplemented stub in Elm

Tags: elm

Does Elm have an expression that produces bottom/diverges, like Haskell's `error` or Rust's `unimplemented!()`?

e.g.

```elm
map : (a -> b) -> List a -> List b
map = unimplemented
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, `Debug.crash` has the type `String -> a` which you can use like this:

```
map : (a -> b) -> List a -> List b
map = Debug.crash "unimplemented"
```